# Find reason for Brew-error 256 (for mariadb), when running brew list services

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

On my Mac, when I write: `sudo brew services list` I get this result:

```txt
Name    Status     User File
------------------------------
dnsmasq started    root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb error  256 root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx   started    root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php@7.4 started    root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4.plist
```

Yesterday I was battling a problem, where I got this result:

```txt
Name    Status     User File
------------------------------
dnsmasq error  512 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb started    root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx   error  256 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php@7.4 started    root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4.plist
```

**Question1:** What does that `256` and `512` mean?

**Questions2:** Where do I find the error-descriptions?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Check `/usr/local/var/log`

I tried to do this:

```txt
tail -f **/*.log
```

But I didn't find anything useful.

---

### Solution attempt 2: Search for latest modified after restarting service

I tried restarting the service: `sudo brew services restart mariadb`

... and then list the latest modified files like this:

```txt
find . -cmin -15
```

But that lists nothing.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Getting info: `sudo brew services info mariadb`

With that command I just get this output:

```txt
mariadb (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
```

But no help regarding this `256`-error.

---

### Solution attempt 4: Add the `-d` flag to `brew services`

Thanks to Luuk for the suggestion of adding the `-d` (debug flag).

When I run : `sudo brew services -d list`, then it outputs this:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libtermkey.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/git-quick-stats.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/git-lfs.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vim.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libtiff.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libtool.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gmp.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libiconv.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/wget.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/msgpack.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/tree-sitter.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/wp-cli.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libidn2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/roots/homebrew-tap/Formula/trellis-cli.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libpng.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ncurses.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/unibilium.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mariadb.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gdbm.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mpdecimal.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libuv.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/freetype.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/argon2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/rtmpdump.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/imath.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/boost.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libavif.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/fmt.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libunistring.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libyaml.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/apr-util.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/brotli.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/icu4c.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/composer.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/perl.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glib.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/readline.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/aom.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/lz4.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/awscli.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/webp.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/sqlite.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/c-ares.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/yarn.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/xz.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/unixodbc.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nvm.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libnghttp2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/lua.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/openexr.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/fontconfig.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ansible.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/double-conversion.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gflags.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/jakehilborn/homebrew-jakehilborn/Formula/displayplacer.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/curl.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/giflib.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/php@7.4.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/phpunit.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mecab-ipadic.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/krb5.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nginx.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/freetds.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libvmaf.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ca-certificates.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gettext.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/luajit-openresty.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libssh2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/zstd.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/watchman.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libsodium.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/apr.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/autoconf.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libpq.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/aspell.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/tidy-html5.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/m4.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/oniguruma.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gd.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/pcre2.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/romkatv/homebrew-powerlevel10k/Formula/powerlevel10k.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libevent.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/pcre.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/jpeg-xl.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/python@3.10.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mecab.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/six.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/jpeg.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libzip.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/zsh.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/neovim.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/openldap.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/groonga.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/folly.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/luv.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/protobuf.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ruby.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/fzf.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libffi.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/python@3.9.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/berkeley-db.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/dnsmasq.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libvterm.rb
```

---

### Solution attempt 5: Add debug flag, when restarting `mariadb`

If I do this: `sudo brew services restart mariadb -d`

Then it outputs this:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mariadb.rb
Stopping `mariadb`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
Warning: Taking root:admin ownership of some mariadb paths:
  /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.7.3/bin
  /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.7.3/bin/mariadbd-safe
  /usr/local/opt/mariadb
  /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/mariadb
This will require manual removal of these paths using `sudo rm` on
brew upgrade/reinstall/uninstall.
Warning: mariadb must be run as non-root to start at user login!
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
```

The only different compared to the "non`-d`"-version is that the first line is omitted, without the debug-flag.

But the error persists after this. And what's extra weird is that Mariadb is working, even though this error is present: I'm working on a local development environment, where I'm making changes in the MariaDB and everything.

Comment: error 256 is given when checking  "prints an error code" (see #line 75-83 [lib_spec.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/blob/master/spec/homebrew/commands/list_spec.rb) )

Comment: I am not experienced enough in Ruby code to find how checking  is done 

Comment: Does: `brew services -d` give ay useful hints, when this is happening?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Luuk . I've just updated the question with the result of adding that `-d` flag.

Comment: Thanks, but I am just curious about the output when it throws the `256` error (and only when it's different from what you just added )

Comment: Ah! I see... I updated the question again, hopefully, with the info you're requesting. :-)

Comment: The warning "Warning: mariadb must be run as non-root to start at user login!" is the reason for this behavior. Solve this (with mariadb), and your problem (with brew) is gone.

Comment: How do I solve that? It would be smart if that warning came with a word of advice. And also - one is a warning, and the other is an error. How do you know that the two are connected?

Comment: MariaDB is short about this [Running mysqld as root](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mysqld-as-root/), but MySQL has some more explanation: [How to Run MySQL as a Normal User](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html).  And, please, do check if your backup is correct before doing anything that might break your database which might have valuable data in it!)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the service is not even running with or without the -d flag if started as root.

The way I troubleshooted, the problem was trying torun mariadb as root

```
> sudo mariadb
```

You'll see that

```
....
....
....
mariadbd: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
```

Edit /usr/local/etc/my.cnf, and add the following

```
[server]
user=your_username
```

Now start the service as root with or without the -d flag.

```
> sudo brew services start mariadb
```

You shouldn't see error 256. Alternatively you could add the option --user=your_username in homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist

```
sudo brew services info mariadb
mariadb (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
Running: ✔
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
User: root
PID: ?????
```

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to Ventura, ran `brew upgrade` and error 256 appeared. It turned out mariadb couldn't write to the error log. In `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` it says:

```
# run "sudo touch /var/log/mariadb-err.log; sudo chmod 766 /var/log/mariadb-err.log" so the server can write to the log.
```

So I did that and could connect again.